# What is this children's book referenced in Little Dorrit?

Tags: identification-request, charles-dickens, little-dorrit

In *Little Dorrit*, Dickens writes:

> A communication of great trap-doors in the floor and roof with the workshop above and the workshop below, made a shaft of light in this perspective, which brought to Clennam’s mind the child’s old picture-book, where similar rays were the witnesses of Abel’s murder.

What is this book Dickens refers to? Bonus points if you can post the picture.

Comment: Seems possible this is a generic rather than a specific reference - Abel's murder makes it sound like it's a book of Bible stories for children, which were probably commonplace to the Victorian middle classes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's possibly [The Christian's Complete Family Bible](https://books.google.com/books?id=HqRDnsvVh5oC&pg=PA1&dq=%22cain%20and%20abel%22%20illustrated&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&source=gb_mobile_search&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwilp57w1sKDAxVxGFkFHWROBwMQuwV6BAgHEAY#v=onepage&q&f=false) (1807), which depicts Cain standing beside a dead Abel, and in the background there's both the devil aflame and a sunbeam through the clouds:

[image: Top text: "Cain and Abel, where is Abel thy brother?" Bottom text: Engraved Nuttall's Family Bible, 1806]

While children's Bibles did exist at that point, this wasn't one of them. It's a Bible proper with annotations and 40 engravings across the entire publication. I guess parents were supposed to read to their family from it.

Comment: Unless that is some then-common trope, since vanished, about how the murder of Abel should be depicted, yeah, that’s the image.

Comment: This is very likely the picture that Dickens had in mind, and if it isn't, it must be very similar. Great work finding it!

Answer (score 2):

I think Matt is right - that it refers to a conventional way of  drawing a beam of light coming down from the sky to indicate that God sees something. I don't know whether Dickens had a particular illustration in mind, from a late-18th century child's book of Bible stories. Perhaps an expert on early children's books would know.

For an example of such a beam, see the frontispiece of [Eikon Basilike](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eikon_Basilike).